# [GSI_LOGGER]: The given login_uri is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: google-signin

I want to Sign In with Google for Web, and I use HTML api with data-login_uri, here the code:

```html
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/google/callback"
     data-itp_support="true">
</div>
```

and I have added data-login_uri to the Authorized redirect URIs in the Google APIs console.

[image]

When I click the google login button, the redirect page is white, and the console logs `[GSI_LOGGER]: The given login_uri is not allowed for the given client ID.`. Can someone have solutions?

I have seen docs https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/integrate#sign_in_with_google_button_considerations.

Comment: Did you double-check that you are using http, not https?

Comment: Yes. The redirect url is: `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&ux_mode=redirect&login_uri=http://localhost:8080/google/callback&ui_mode=card&context=signin&as=RkeoCextCB6PMEQ0L5Kx1Q&g_csrf_token=107e6f184545bd7b&origin=http://localhost:8080`